# import selected gmail contacts in php

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, preg-match

I am using oauth to import contacts via gmail:
 [Import Gmail or Google contacts using Google Contacts Data API and OAuth 2.0 in PHP](http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/)

However, i want to display only those results which have @xyz.com in their emails. I tried by modifying the last statement of oauth.php to this:

```
foreach ($result as $title) {
if(preg_match("/@xyz.com/",$title->attributes()->address))
echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
}
```

But i am not getting any results. 
And not all of the contacts are imported. I believe that @xyz.com is not being fed back by gmail, though the user has sent and received mails from @xyz.com. Who are being referred as contacts here?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
foreach ($result as $title) 
{
    if(strpos($title->attributes()->address, '@xyz.com') !== false)
    {
        echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try echoing `$title->attributes()->address`. What does it give you?

Comment: I have somewhat 300 contacts and many are from xyz.com. I am using the email address like somewhat@xyz.com. However, none of the contacts are being fed back to display. Why?

Comment: Echo the variable I indicated above outside of the `if()` statement. How do they look?

Comment: only some of the contacts are bein displayed.. somwhat like 40-50 out of 300

Comment: and it throws an error saying 
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\xampp\htdocs\oauth\oauth.php:80 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\oauth\oauth.php(80): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\oauth\oauth.php on line 80

Comment: Then you might need to ask another question, as that is beyond the scope of your initial query.

Comment: can you help me on this? through chat? it's really important

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23420/discussion-between-user2003663-and-benm)